# Using Pandas to drop duplicates for subsets of rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset where I'd like to remove duplicates from 1 column based on a subset of rows of another column. So for example I have the table below:

| Date | ID | Fruit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-2-2 | 1 | Apple |
| 2021-2-2 | 1 | Pear |
| 2021-2-2 | 1 | Apple |
| 2021-2-2 | 2 | Pear |
| 2021-2-2 | 2 | Pear |
| 2021-2-2 | 2 | Apple |
| 2021-3-2 | 3 | Apple |
| 2021-3-2 | 3 | Apple |

And I want the table to look like this:

| Date | ID | Fruit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-2-2 | 1 | Apple |
| 2021-2-2 | 1 | Pear |
| 2021-2-2 | 2 | Pear |
| 2021-2-2 | 2 | Apple |
| 2021-3-2 | 3 | Apple |

So I'm trying to remove duplicates within the rows of the same ID number only.

This is what I've tried:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import re
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_excel('Example.xlsx',
                    usecols=("A:E"), sheet_name=('Data'))

df_Example = df.loc[(((df)["StateNumber"].isin([1]) & (df["CountyNumber"].isin([5,6]))) | ((df)["StateNumber"].isin([3]) & (df["CountyNumber"].isin([8]))))]

df_Example1 = df_Example.sort_values("ID").drop_duplicates("Fruit", keep="first").sort_index()
print(df_Example1)
```

Mainly just the bottom line of code is for the duplicate removal part. This removes all duplicates regardless of ID number instead of just duplicates that fall under an ID number. I've also tried some things with groupby or categorical but have not had luck yet.

Answer (score 1):

You can drop duplicates based on `subset`.

If you need to add two subset you can use:

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['ID', 'Fruit'], keep='first')
```